# Display picture on top of heatmat in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, heatmap

I have a heat map plot using matplotlib and I want to superimpose small images on top of the heat map. This it the code for the heatmap:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data=np.random.rand(7,7)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(data.transpose(), extent=[0, 7, 0, 7])
transform = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().scale(1,np.cos(np.pi/6)).skew_deg(-30, 0)
trans_data = transform + ax.transData
im.set_transform(trans_data)
ax.set_xlim(-6/np.cos(np.pi/6)*np.sin(np.pi/6),7)

#just removing ticks and hiding axis spines
plt.tick_params(axis='x', bottom=False)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', left=False)
for child in ax.get_children():
    if isinstance(child,mpl.spines.Spine):
        child.set_color('w')
ticks=np.linspace(1,7,7)
ax.set_xticklabels(ticks.astype(int).astype(str))
ax.set_xticks(ticks-0.5)
ax.set_yticks([])
for i in ticks:
    plt.text(-.5,i-.67,str(int(i)),transform=trans_data)

cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax, orientation='horizontal', shrink=.6)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel("",rotation=0, va="bottom")

plt.savefig('test.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

The heat map maps to an atomic structure, and I would like to insert little figures of the atoms in the appropriate (skewed) squares, like this:

[image: Desired results: orange atom on top of head map, centered in one of the squares]

Preferably I want it in a way that preserves the atom's position in the specified square also if I change the size of the figure or so. I will likely run through a number of iterations of the figure before it's finalized form, and I want it to be as convenient as possible to make changes.

So far, the ideas I've had on how to solve my issue is:

1. to insert the atoms as annotations as in [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/demo_annotation_box.html) example. With this I don't know how to get rid of the white box around the atom though.
2. to make the plot and save as png, then make a second python script which loads the plot and atom as images and exchanges part of the plot's data array for the atom's data array, and saves this as a new image. This seems like a very inelegant solution, and would not allow for easy changes.

Comment: Your first solution is the way to go. Can you show what you have tried and what you mean by "the white box around the atom"?

Comment: How are your "atom" images stored? Or are they generated? Are they in a .png format with transparency? Note that adding transparency afterwards loses some quality.